# Passing Parameters to powershell script in scheduled task

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to create a scheduled task that will run a Powershell script with 1 parameter - this is on Server 2012 with Powershell v5 installed.  So far I have been able to get the task to run, but it doesn't recognize my param value - the value is null in my script that I am calling.  Here is what I have to create the scheduled task:

```
$TicketTime = "9:00pm"
$EmpID = "1234"
$Firstname = "Test"
$Lastname = "User"

$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Argument "-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\Scripts\Term.ps1 -EmpID '$EmpID'"
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At "03/29/2016 $TicketTime"
$Task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Trigger $Trigger -Settings (New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet)
$Task | Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "$Firstname $Lastname" -User "myuser" -Password "mypass"
```

This will execute successfully, but will not recognize the -EmpID parameter.  I have also tried -Command instead of -File for the Argument value but I get the same result.

```
-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "& C:\Scripts\Term.ps1 -EmpID 1234"
```

Single quotes around the param doesn't seem to do anything either

```
-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "& C:\Scripts\Term.ps1 -EmpID '1234'"
```

So far nothing I do will get the param to pass.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try and declare your parameters as positional rather than named:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(Position=0)]
    [string]$Ticket
)

"-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\Scripts\Term.ps1 '$EmpID'"
```

Then you can drop the -ParamName and pass it in using position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-File` option, you just need to separate out the string:

Change

```
-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "& C:\Scripts\Term.ps1 -EmpID 1234"
```

to

```
-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "C:\Scripts\Term.ps1" -EmpID "1234"
```

The full string out look like this:

```
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Argument "-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File `"C:\Scripts\Term.ps1`" -EmpID `"$EmpID`""
```